# Introduction to local macros and foreach loops not replicable?

Tags: loops, foreach, syntax-error, histogram, stata

I’m doing a Stata tutorial to try and catch up on macros, loops and data visualization. I tried replicating the syntax patterns from different tutorials using my own data, and Stata insists that the syntax is incorrect (even when it’s identical save for the variable names). It displays nothing for the local macro, and then the foreach command generates endless "not allowed" errors. I am now really confused.

I would like to, ideally, create a macro that substitutes for a set of variables, and create a loop that generates (and saves) tailored histograms for each variable in that macro.

Can someone please identify why the following syntax is invalid?

I’ve included my current iteration, and a copy of the tutorial syntax. I was wondering if maybe the tutorial has downloaded something that permits this particular syntax (Youtube's "Anatomy of a loop in Stata using foreach" video by Stata Analysis101). I've dropped them a note, but in the meantime...

anyone?

Current iteration (run from .do file):

```
local caseloadA_5 avVFTE_total_5 avVPTE_total_5 PEcaseloadA_5 PEcaseloadB_5 PTPEcaseloadC_5
foreach var of varlist `caseloadA_5' {

histogram `var', ///
bin(40) start(0) ///
percent ///
addplot(fcolor(green%60) lcolor(black%70)) ///
ytitle("Affiliates") ///
xtitle("`var'") ///
legend(off) ///
subtitle("2021-2022: `var'") ///
saving("\\STLFS01\Public\Tatiana Gochez-Kerr\Task - APR\Annual APR\Annual APR 2021-2022\`var'.gph", replace)
}
```

sample errors:

```
barw(0.9) is not a twoway plot type
r(198);
fcolor(green%60) is not a twoway plot type
r(198);
option kdenopts() not allowed
r(198);
option ytitle() not allowed
r(198);
option xtitle() not allowed
r(198);
option legend() not allowed
r(198);
option saving() not allowed
r(198);
```

Tutorial syntax:

```
local x size_cat status death_percent

foreach y of varlist `x' {
histogram `y', ///
percent ///
color(erose%45) ///
ylabel(, valuelabel) ///
xtitle("`y'") ///
subtitle("Histograms for aggregate hospital data 2012") ///
graphregion(color(white))
saving("$pp/graphres/`y'", replace)
}
```

Comment: You are possibly trying to use `///` interactively. Such continuation syntax is only allowed in do-files and programs. Also, when that is allowed you still need such a continuation before the option call to `saving()`.

Comment: I didn't watch all the tutorial but it's made clear near the beginning that the speaker is using the Do-file Editor.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We can't replicate your code without the dataset, your directory structure, or the definition of your global macro.

Comment: I apologize, but the macro thing is new for me. Do I need a global macro with my local macro?

Comment: No; you don't need a global macro for anything here. The point is one of principle: it is more difficult to discuss code when it includes a global macro that isn't defined. The code we **can** comment on  is what you call your current iteration, and there is nothing in that that doesn't work for me in a context I can use, as my answer indicates.  I can guess that if you define the local macro in one place and refer to another, it won't be visible. That's what `local` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using a do-file.

```
sysuse auto, clear 

foreach y in price mpg weight { 
    
histogram `y', ///
percent ///
color(erose%45) ///
ylabel(, valuelabel) ///
xtitle("`y'") ///
subtitle("Histograms for auto data") ///
graphregion(color(white)) ///
saving("`y'", replace)

}
```

It's a matter of style not syntax, but the tutorial's `foreach` syntax is more indirect than it needs to be.

If you want to put a list of variable names in a local macro as in

```
local myvars price mpg weight
```

then you can follow with

```
foreach y of local myvars {
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think maybe that's where I'm getting confused? I can duplicate it with the exact same data, but I can't do it with my own data. I *have* been running it as .do files (sorry, I didn't include the .end of do-file syntax), and I modified to reflect your suggestion, and I got no errors but also no histogram.

Comment: That's very unfortunate but I can see nothing in your comment that adds information I can use. Everything hinges on your own data that we can't see.

Comment: Attempting this with the auto data, I got the graphs to work, but they don't save to anywhere I can access? I used your same code, both the shorthand local macro and the other one (thank you). I can't seem to find any indication of *where* the graphs saved though.    
(bin=8, start=3291, width=1576.875)
file price.gph saved
(bin=8, start=12, width=3.625)
file mpg.gph saved
(bin=8, start=1760, width=385)
file weight.gph saved

Comment: They are saved in the directory or folder in which you are working.

Comment: Try dir *.gph in your current directory.

Comment: Hi again - I thought I'd posted a response, but it looks like I didn't - I figured out the working directory and it's fixed now, so I can find what I save. Thank you for your help!! I can make foreach work for my histograms now, but it still gives syntax errors when I try to switch graph formats. I can get the graphing command to work, but the designs often fail - ex, from histogram to scatterplot it rejected the "m" (marker design - ex: option mcolor() not allowed) syntax:   twoway (scatter `var' headroom), mcolor(dknavy) msize(vsmall) msymbol(smplus) title(`var' compared with headroom)

Comment: Take out the first pair of parentheses around `scatter ... headroom`.